# Google Tag Manager and Single Page apps

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm trying to integrate Google Tag Manager with my Ember app. I'm having a hard time understanding how to notify GTM that the page changed, and send a page view event.

I've read a lot of things online, mostly working around creating a new variable for a "virtual page" or something, but obviously this is far from ideal.

I'd like to be able to just use `dataLayer.push` to notify the page actually changed. Is there an easy way out I didn't find or is it really a pain to track with GTM on SPA?

Comment: Curious, if VPVs are far from ideal, then what is ideal to you in your case of an SPA. VPVs are almost the only option for you, unless, of course, you change the page architecture of your site. That said, to use VPVs, you need to push an event each time the 'page' changes, and then trigger a pageview tag that fires and sets a new page name (ie. your VPV).

Comment: @nyuen you seem to know what you're talking about. I was just wondering why it wasn't as easy as it is with GA, where I could just do a `ga('send', 'pageview')` and GA would be notify the page changed.

Comment: @nyuen also, can GA be then notify the page changed directly from GTM, so I don't have to trigger `ga('send', 'pageview')` then `dataLayer.push`?

Comment: I don't think it would be any easier with just GA. The tricky part is telling GA *when* to fire the pageview, because as you might already know, just scrolling down a page won't fire pageviews unless you tell GA "hey, the user just scrolled to this section - fire an event!". So this is what you may need to do - push events into the dataLayer so that your pageview tag can know when to fire.

Comment: Well I'm currently only using GA when a page changes, nothing very specific. The thing is GA is already configured for this event, when GTM has to be configured, right?

Comment: So sounds like you have both GA and GTM running at the same time? If you are not using GTM to track  your pageviews then you need to send a GA pageview with the VPV when the next 'page' is viewed.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This was asked quite a while ago. With the current feature set of GTM, you can easily set up SPA page tracking without much trouble.

First, go to `Triggers` and create a new trigger. Select `History Change` as the trigger type. This will create a trigger that fires every time the location history changes.

Then create a new `Tag` of `Universal Analytics` type and set it up as per the screenshot below.

[[image: Universal Analytics tag configuration1]

As for the trigger, set the previously defined History Change trigger, and you're done. Every time a navigation occurs in your SPA, a page view event with the proper page path will be triggered.

EDIT: as `trognaders` pointed out in a comment, this does not track the initial page view. To remedy, simply add an additional trigger for your tag that fires on the Page View event (All Pages). See screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: you're a true saver, been vainly trying everything listed in the web, all the crazy solutions, yours is the simplest and works just like a charm. Thousand thanks. I just would like to mention for other people in the same trouble that your steps MUST be done after creating the basic `Universal analytics` Tag + `Page view` Trigger :)

Comment: can confirm this still works great for Ember apps. Just set this up in a 3.10 ember app. Only thing not shown in the screenshot above is that you need to add your GA tracking id in the "Tracking ID" input.

Comment: I'm a bit late to the party, but can you guys please share the exact script you have added to your SPA to make this work?

Comment: @Hame there is no script involved in the SPA. That is the beauty of it, you only need GTM configuration as detailed above, and the page view events will automatically be tracked.

Comment: @trognanders that is quite possibly true, I'll have to check. In that case,you just need to add an additional trigger for the tag (All Pages / Page view), and you're all set. Updated my answer.

Comment: @AndrásSzepesházi Using both triggers does appear to be pretty standard, and it is how I implemented our thing. Thank you for the answer; it helped a lot!

Comment: @AndrásSzepesházi I'm not sure what you mean when you say only the GTM configuration is needed. Here's the script I've added to my SPA to make it work:
`(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
  new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
  j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
  'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
  })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXXX');`

Comment: This solution triggers a pageview event twice for the first page. Is there any "standard" solution for this?

Answer (score 22):

You definitely need to push events into the dataLayer which you can then trigger a GA page view tag in GTM.  So to push an event into the DL:

```
dataLayer.push({'event':'virtualPageView'});
```

Then setup a trigger called 'vpv' which fires on a custom event called 'virtualPageView'.  Add that trigger to a GA tag.

The best thing to do is also send through the details of the virtual page when you send the event.  This way you can set up variables that pull these dataLayer property values into the page view call.  So you might do this:

```
dataLayer.push({
  'event':'virtualPageView',
  'page':{
    'title':'contact us',
    'url':'/contact'
  }
});
```

So you'd setup a variable called 'DL- page title' (for example) which is a dataLayer value of 'page.title' and another variable called 'DL - page url' which is a dataLayer value of 'page.url'.

You then setup a new Universal Analytics tag which has all your usual pageview settings but with 2 'Fields to Set' (under More Settings).  Set 'title' to {{DL-page title}} and 'page' to {{DL - page url}}

Finally set the trigger to 'vpv' and you'll find everytime you push the event + data into the datalayer you'll get a pageView fired off with your virtual page's title and virtual url.

Comment: I've tried this and I had one major issue as I keep pushing event to dataLayer I get an exponential amount of event as the dataLayer is persistent across pages.

Comment: @Sunny I presume you mean you get a large dataLayer array because you keep pushing page view events into it.  This is a drawback of using the DL like this in a single page app.  Don't forget the DL is just an array sat on a web page.  you can clear it out at anytime if you choose.

Comment: @dmpg_tom @Sunny `dataLayer` has a limit of 300 entries and will clean itself up as needed: http://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/datalayer-declaration-vs-push/#comment-608025