# How to push to google analytics page title on SPA

Tags: google-analytics, single-page-application, google-tag-manager

good evening everyone,

I'm trying to use GTM for analytics on my SPA website, I manage to get analytics working thanks to this post by @András Szepesházi: [Google Tag Manager and Single Page apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33299429/google-tag-manager-and-single-page-apps), but i just realized that the page title isn't being pushed to analytics. I tried to created new variables but didn't manage to make it work. Any ideas how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Based on the example of your link, after creating the variables and managing the push on page change, you need to setup the Universal Analytics with 2 'Fields to Set':

- 'title' to {{DL-page title}}
- 'page' to {{DL - page url}}

In Google Tag Manager Analytics Tag you will have a situation like the following:

[image]

So you send both the page and the title with the same Analytics hit.

Comment: Thanks @Michele for taking the time to answer. That's exactly what i did, `page` is a built-in variable `{{Page Path}}` and `title` a javascript variable with the value `document.title`. But it doesn't work :/

Comment: Try to see in preview mode the value of 'javascript variable' of the title when trigger is 'Page View' (gtm.js). Is it undefined?

Comment: Hmm, it sends the wrong data (site name), I'm using NuxtJs, do you think it has something to do with it??

Comment: I haven't used this framework, do you use it to retrieve the title inside Tag Manager?

Comment: sorry, didn't receive a notification :/ actually i dodn't use nuxt to retrieve the data, i use the javascript variable created in GTM.

Comment: At this point the problem I would say is in JavaScript, not in GTM.

Comment: OK, thanks, i'll try to investigate deeply and hope to find the solution!

Comment: Great. It depended on JavaScript?